# chrome extension: executeScript refreshes popup.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to have a chrome extension that will inject a script to the active tab, and once it's done I want to have a flag that will change once the script was injected. The injection is working fine and so does the callback function.
But, after the callback function popup.html refresh itself so i no longer have that flag saved. Is there a way to prevent this refresh and continue to store this value?
what i have so far:
manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "test"
, "version": "1.0"
, "author": "test"
, "manifest_version": 2
, "description": "test"
, "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
, "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "test"
    , "default_icon": "images/test.png"
    , "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
, "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*"],
        "js": ["js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js", "js/bootstrap.min.js"]
    }
]
```

}

popup.js:

```
var flag = false;
   function runScript(product) {
var p = product;
var config = {
    product: p
};
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(config)
}, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'js/content.js'
    }, function (callback) {
        if (callback) {
            flag = true;
            console.log(flag);
        }
    });
});
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
$('#advenced').on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdown").toggle();
    return false;
});
var settings = [];
$("#apply").click(function () {
    form = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-rel'));
    //dothings here
    if (settings.length > 0) {
        runScript(settings);
    }
});
}, false);
```

Comment: The popup exists only while it's shown. Once it's closed no variables or code persist. You'll need to save the values in chrome.storage or the old HTML5 `localStorage`.

Comment: Use [`chrome.storeage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to store the value.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it. But as far as my question goes, is there any way to stop the page from refreshing? It happens when the popup is still open.

Comment: There's something else wrong in that case. Maybe you're using a `form` without preventing its `submit` event.